# Using Camel to get data from a web service

Tags: java, web-services, apache-camel

There is a lot of information for using Camel with JMS, but I can’t find much on using Camel to request data from a web service. I am wondering if this is even possible to do this directly, or do I need to use some kind of JMS/queue?

Ideally, I want my service (using java DSL) to send out a request to another web service, retrieve the data, and then store this in a file locally. Is it possible to do this in Camel using a simple custom RouteBuilder and a camelContext? I’ve tried setting up my routes using

```
`from(“http:..”).to(“file:...");`
```

but this doesn’t seem to work, as it doesn’t seem to get the data from the web service. From what I've read, I was under the impression that the endpoint `http:` will build the request automatically and route this to a file.

I am now wondering what I could try next, and if this is even possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is definitely possible. The best example to start with is the [CXF-Proxy Example](http://camel.apache.org/cxf-proxy-example.html).  This shows how to invoke a remote web-service from Camel. Feel free to ask specific questions if you run into issues and we can help.

Comment: Awesome, thanks very much for this! I shall take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Also you could use Spring Web Services Component

http://camel.apache.org/spring-web-services.html

In this case, your route would look like:

```
from("<some event to trigger the route>")
.to("spring-ws:<endpoint of the WS you want to use>")
.to("file:<write the WS result>")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind trying things out at the SOAP level you could try out the approaches found here [http://camel.apache.org/soap.html link](http://camel.apache.org/soap.html).  Its worth a look even if you end up using something a little more high level.